# Should we burn with fire "How much XP..." questions?

Tags: discussion, burnination

Seems that every RPG that comes out, there's that question that pops out soon after.

[Total Amount of Experience from 1 to 50](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/47086/total-amount-of-experience-from-1-to-50)

[What is the total amount of exp needed to go from level 1 to 70 (71) in Modern Warfare 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/660/what-is-the-total-amount-of-exp-needed-to-go-from-level-1-to-70-71-in-modern-w)

[How much experience is required for each level?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67760/how-much-experience-is-required-for-each-level)

[Is there a list of experience needed to reach each level for GoW3?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33339/is-there-a-list-of-experience-needed-to-reach-each-level-for-gow3?rq=1)

Should we not want those generic questions? I don't really see the use of knowing it takes exactly 24M exp to get from level 1 to 60 in Diablo.

Seems these questions are an easy way to score points and do not bring else more to the game and/or the site.

So, should we take them as off subject?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They're often stupid questions, but not off topic.

Downvote them if you want to, but I wouldn't close/delete them personally.

Comment: With the voting on that question, I guess everybody thinks like you.